# Connecting Raspberry PI 2 to WIFI

Tags: wifi

I can see my network in the range but unable to connect. Here is my interface file:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Here is my wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

    network={
            ssid="my ssid"
            key_mgmt=NONE
            wep_key0="ssid password"
    }
```

Please let me know what am I missing.

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:59:af:de  
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b77:bbdd:2f6b:68a6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20458 (19.9 KiB)  TX bytes:14131 (13.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:16656 (16.2 KiB)  TX bytes:16656 (16.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:62:7f:74  
          inet6 addr: fe80::19cb:528d:d1cc:d3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After wpa_supplicant change:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

    network={
            ssid="my ssid"
            key_mgmt=WAP-PSK
            wep_key0="ssid password"
    }
```

Comment: Is your access point using WEP? Does your WiFi dongle support wep? What is the output of lsusb, what is the output of ifconfig?

Comment: I have added output of Isusb and ifconfig. I think I have WPA2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: assuming you have wpa2 you may should try key_mgmt=WPA-PSK in place of key_mgmt=NONE

Comment: I did the change as recommended and now I cant see any networks in the range and when I hover my mouse on wireless sigh on top right it says -eth0: configures; wlan0: Not assosiated. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure your router uses WPA?

Comment: Yes. I check under wireless status in 192.168.1.1 and also on my laptop under network preferences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33695/discussion-between-ddesai-and-steve-robillard).

Answer (score 1):

To connect your Raspberry Pi to your WiFi, just use
`sudo wpa_supplicant your_ssid >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

`wpa_supplicant` requires you to enter your WiFi-password and press Enter. `wpa_supplicant` then adds the required information needed for connection to your `wpa_supplicant.conf`-file. I think, your RPi will connect automatically after a few seconds. If not, just reboot your RPi and you should be fine. I did this with several RPi's and several networks.

**Note:** This only works with WPA-PSK-networks (WPA with static password). Nearly every home-network uses WPA-PSK and most other do too. If the network uses WEP, kindly ask the network-administrator to change to WPA or change it yourself, because WEP is deprecated. For any other network-configurations you might have to edit the `wpa_supplicant.conf`-file manually. If so, feel free to share your experience here.

Answer (score -1):

Just delete all related with wlan1 and change manual to auto in the interfaces file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to explain this a little further, e.g. present the changed lines of the config to make it easier to understand and provide an explanation why it does what it does.

Comment: I agree with @Ghanima, a little more context is required. If you could provide a formatted example that would be great.